# How Can I add two very large numbers in excel?

Tags: excel

I want to store two very large numbers in excel and then add them. my numbers are like this:

324930313630311035156280330632053510851055146511

when I type this number in a cell, it is shown for only 15 digits. of course I know that **I can change the format cell to text**, but when I change it to text, it is not calculable.

many thanks

Comment: @Mech: when I do this, the addition is converted to 2.43091E+46. how to convert this scientific number to original number? excuse me I'm beginner in excel. many thanks

Comment: If you need to do math on numbers of that size, you will need to write a VBA math routine to handle it. An old one, which still works (albeit with some glitches) is called [xNumbers](http://www.thetropicalevents.com/Xnumbers60.htm).  It has been around for a long time, but is not being supported.  However, it will work with the newer versions of excel, although, because of the way in which it was coded, accessing the HELP file for the functions is a bit difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a user defined function that will add really big positive integers that have been entered in string format.  The udf returns string format to preserve all the digits:

```
Public Function superadd(s1 As String, s2 As String) As String
    Dim L1 As Long, L2 As Long, L3 As Long, Carry As Long
    Dim v1 As Long, v2 As Long, zum As Long
    L1 = Len(s1)
    L2 = Len(s2)
    L3 = Application.Max(L1, L2)
    If L1 > L2 Then
        For i = 1 To L1 - L2
            s2 = "0" & s2
        Next i
    Else
        For i = 1 To L2 - L1
            s1 = "0" & s1
        Next i
    End If
    
    Carry = 0
    For i = L3 To 1 Step -1
        v1 = CLng(Mid(s1, i, 1))
        v2 = CLng(Mid(s2, i, 1))
        zum = v1 + v2 + Carry
        If i = 1 Then
            superadd = CStr(zum) & superadd
            Exit For
        Else
            If zum > 9 Then
                superadd = Right(CStr(zum), 1) & superadd
                Carry = CLng(Left(CStr(zum), 1))
            Else
                superadd = CStr(zum) & superadd
                Carry = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Used like:

[image]