# I have a problem with changing Cell Type from General to Number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When I try to convert Large number (ex: 8996609817110286118) from General to Number, the result becomes: 8.99661E+18 ( 8996609817110280000), It forces this approximation, which I don't want)

[Before Changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reVjk.png)

[After Changing to Number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p00Yt.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There's no exact number representation in excel for numbers this big. You can either use strings instead of numbers (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63972222/how-can-i-add-two-very-large-numbers-in-excel)), or live with the reduced accuracy. You did not specify what these numbers represent, but there are almost no applications that require physical quantities to be that accurate.

Comment: This is a serial number of a SIM card (ICCID) so accuracy is important. I want to be able to sort these numbers, and use other functions, it is not doable unless the cell type is Number.

Comment: Text can be sorted, too. You won't ever want to add or multiply these serial numbers, so no, it does not need to be a number.